# Hand-coded quicksort is slower on smaller integers

Tags: c++, sorting

When comparing my quicksort implementation with std::sort on my compiler and my implementation of mergesort, I noticed an odd pattern on large data sets: when operating on 64 bit integers, quicksort is consistently faster than mergesort; however, on smaller int  sizes quicksort gets slower and mergesort gets faster.

Here is the testing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <limits>
#include <functional>

#include <cstdint>


template <typename Iterator>
void insertion_sort(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    using namespace std;

    Iterator head = first;
    Iterator new_position;

    while(head != last)
    {
        new_position = head;
        while(new_position != first && *new_position < *prev(new_position))
        {
            swap(*new_position, *prev(new_position));
            --new_position;
        }
        ++head;
    }
}

template <typename Iterator>
void recursive_mergesort_impl(Iterator first, Iterator last, std::vector<typename Iterator::value_type>& temp)
{
    if(last - first > 32)
    {
        auto middle = first + (last-first)/2;
        recursive_mergesort_impl(first, middle, temp);
        recursive_mergesort_impl(middle, last, temp);
        auto last_merged = merge_move(first, middle, middle, last, temp.begin());
        std::move(temp.begin(), last_merged, first);
    }
    else
    {
        insertion_sort(first, last);
    }
}

template <typename Iterator>
void recursive_mergesort(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    std::vector<typename Iterator::value_type> temp(last-first);
    recursive_mergesort_impl(first, last, temp);
}

// Pick a pivot and move it to front of range
template <typename Iterator>
template <typename Iterator>
void quicksort_pivot_back(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    using namespace std;

    auto middle = first + (last-first)/2;
    auto last_elem = prev(last);
    Iterator pivot;

    if(*first < *middle)
    {
        if(*middle < *last_elem)
            pivot = middle;
        else if(*first < *last_elem)
            pivot = last_elem;
        else
            pivot = first;
    }
    else if(*first < *last_elem)
        pivot = first;
    else if(*middle < *last_elem)
        pivot = last_elem;
    else
        pivot = middle;

    swap(*last_elem, *pivot);
}

template <typename Iterator, typename Function>
std::pair<Iterator, Iterator> quicksort_partition(Iterator first, Iterator last, Function pivot_select)
{
    using namespace std;

    pivot_select(first, last);

    auto pivot = prev(last);
    auto bottom = first;
    auto top = pivot;

    while(bottom != top)
    {
        if(*bottom < *pivot) ++bottom;
        else swap(*bottom, *--top);
    }

    swap(*pivot, *top++);

    return make_pair(bottom, top);
}

template <typename Iterator>
void quicksort_loop(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    using namespace std;

    while(last - first > 32)
    {
        auto bounds = quicksort_partition(first, last, quicksort_pivot_back<Iterator>);

        quicksort_loop(bounds.second, last);
        last = bounds.first;
    }
}


template <typename Iterator>
void quicksort(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    quicksort_loop(first, last);
    insertion_sort(first, last);
}

template <typename IntType = uint64_t, typename Duration = std::chrono::microseconds, typename Timer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, typename Function, typename Generator>
void run_trial(Function sort_func, Generator gen, std::string name, std::size_t trial_size, std::size_t trial_count)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    vector<IntType> data(trial_size);

    Duration elapsed(0);

    cout << "Sorting with " << name << endl;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < trial_count; ++i)
    {
        generate(data.begin(), data.end(), gen);

        auto start = Timer::now();
        sort_func(data.begin(), data.end());
        auto finish = Timer::now();

        elapsed += duration_cast<Duration>(finish-start);
    }

    cout << "Done. Average elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() / trial_count << endl;
    cout << "Is correct: " << is_sorted(data.begin(), data.end()) << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    using int_type = uint64_t;
    const size_t trial_size = 12800000;
    const int trial_count = 15;

    vector<int_type> data(trial_size);
    uniform_int_distribution<int_type> distr;
    mt19937_64 rnd;

    run_trial<int_type>(recursive_mergesort<vector<int_type>::iterator>, bind(distr, rnd), "recursive mergesort", trial_size, trial_count);
    run_trial<int_type>(quicksort<vector<int_type>::iterator>, bind(distr, rnd), "quicksort", trial_size, trial_count);
    run_trial<int_type>(sort<vector<int_type>::iterator>, bind(distr, rnd), "std::sort", trial_size, trial_count);
}
```

Here are times from 15 trials of 12800000 elements:

`uint64_t`:

```
Sorting with recursive mergesort
Done. Average elapsed time: 1725431
Is correct: 1

Sorting with quicksort
Done. Average elapsed time: 1238070
Is correct: 1

Sorting with std::sort
Done. Average elapsed time: 1131464
Is correct: 1
```

`uint16_t`:

```
Sorting with recursive mergesort
Done. Average elapsed time: 1186467
Is correct: 1

Sorting with quicksort
Done. Average elapsed time: 2368535
Is correct: 1

Sorting with std::sort
Done. Average elapsed time: 888517
Is correct: 1
```

I have a feeling that the problem has to do with unaligned memory accesses, however that still makes me wonder why the other algorithms get a speedup while quicksort gets slowed down.

Comment: _'Why is this?'_ Because your measurement's aren't significant! Use a profiling tool, or measure statistically on lots of calls (>1000).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know, I know :) I ran it a few times and got the same result though. I guess I'll make the test a bit more comprehensive just to make sure.

Comment: If you run the program repeately, that won't help to measure in a statistically reliable manner.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I modified it to average results from 15 trials and the difference actually became greater. When I get a chance, I'll run larger trials and perform actual statistical validation. It'll take a while though, because the dataset sizes that cause the quicksort to be so slow are quite large.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for me. Please add includes and missing function(s).

Comment: @moooeeeep It's only standard headers and there are no missing functions, but I added the header includes for convenience sake. Plus, I made a fix in the code here that I forgot to add earlier.

Comment: One of your edits changed a call of `quicksort_pivot_front()` to `quicksort_pivot_back()` but you forgot to add that implementation.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Good catch, I fixed it. It was actually the other way around; I changed the function but forgot to change the call.

Comment: Did you know that `quicksort_pivot_front()` puts the pivot value into `first` but `quicksort_partition()` takes it from `prev(last)`? Maybe I'm crazy but that doesn't look correct.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I take that back, you were right. I'm getting lost in my own edits haha. Changing it again...

Comment: In the future you might have the `pivot_select()` function just return an iterator and let the caller decide whether to swap it around or copy the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `uint16_t`, you're going to get a lot of duplicates in such a large array: 195 occurrences of each of 0 though 65535, in expectation. Without a [three-way ("fat") partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements), or at least one that returns the *middle* of the repeated occurrences of the pivot value in the subarray it's processing, that causes quicksort to go quadratic. (Try a pencil-and-paper execution of a naive quicksort on an array of only zeros to see the effect.)

Comment: +1 Awesome, I didn't think of that. I'll wait to see some other answers before I decide which to accept.

Could this issue be addressed with better pivot selection as well?

Comment: @mebob: note that this hypothesis is testable, by sorting the same set of values, one time stored as 16 bit, and once as 64 bit. A better pivot choice wont help. The problem is that after enough recursions, all values in the subrange are identical. Three-way is the way to go.

Comment: @mebob: no, changing the pivot is not enough. The all-zeros case serves as an example again: the pivot is always the same value.